# Rendering complete Tiled Map on Android with LibGdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, tiled

I am trying to render a Tiled Map on to an Android device. However, when I test it on my android phone, only the top layer is rendered on to the screen (out of two layers total). Is there a way to fix this? I am using Libgdx as well as Tiled Map Editor.

Below is some of the code for my project which implements the Screen interface. The omitted code is not necessary for the question but can be shown if needed.

```
public class Play implements Screen {
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.setView(cam);
    renderer.render();

    /*code ommited*/

    renderer.getSpriteBatch().begin();
    animateAgent(time);

    sr.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    try {
    animateBullets(sr);
    } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}

    renderer.getSpriteBatch().end();
}

public void show() {
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false);
    cam.position.set(0,0,0);
    cam.zoom = 8.0f;
    cam.update();

    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("data/batMap.tmx");
    blocked = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(1);
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

    atlas = new TextureAtlas("data/specOps.txt");
    agent = atlas.createSprites("agent");

/* code ommitted */

    player = new Player(agent,blocked,bullets);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(player);
}
}
```

Here's how it currently looks: 
[image]
and here's how it should look: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are only getting one layer at

```
 blocked = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(1);
```

or are you getting the other layer elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
map.getLayers().get(0).setVisible(true);
map.getLayers().get(1).setVisible(true);
```